# Clear contents of cell based on value in other cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help making my VBA code work. The first part where it hides certain rows works but when I try to clear the contents of cells based on a value in another cell I can not seem to get it to work.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
Dim c As Range
On Error Resume Next
 If Target.Address = "$H$5" Then
    Rows("10:109").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "1"
            Rows("30:109").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Select

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "2"
            Rows("50:109").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Select

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "3"
            Rows("70:109").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Select
 End If

 If Target.Address = "$H$6" Then

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "1"
            Range("C18:D23").Cells.ClearContents

    End Select

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "2"
            Range("C19:D23").Cells.ClearContents

    End Select

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "3"
            Range("C20:D23").Cells.ClearContents

    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get the error ?

Comment: So, what's your error? Did you debug it (step-by-step)? Perhaps, condition isn't met - and hence you don't reach the code which clears contents.

Comment: You're in `Change` event. You should be careful with any manipulations with cells since if you change some value in some cell in this procedure, the `Chang`e event will be fired. Thus, you get a chain of `Change` event. Fortunately, Excel aborts this endless loop at some point. All you need is to place `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the beginning and `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the end.

Comment: It doesnt produce an error which doesnt make sense. All it does is nothing for the second part and the contents remains

Comment: @JohnyL Yeah that worked thank you

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range

On Error Resume Next

If Target.Address = "$H$5" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Rows("10:109").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "1"
                Rows("30:109").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "2"
                Rows("50:109").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "3"
                Rows("70:109").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Target.Address = "$H$6" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "1"
                Range("C18:D23").Cells.ClearContents
            Case "2"
                Range("C19:D23").Cells.ClearContents
            Case "3"
                Range("C20:D23").Cells.ClearContents
        End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: You placed `Application.EnableEvents` *four* times instead of *two*.

Comment: Also arbitrary `On Error Resume Next` ... While this answer may work, I feel like it is supporting some bad  vba programming habits.

Comment: @Rawrplus Do I not need the `On Error Resume Next` ?

Comment: @JohnyL Does the `Application.EnableEvents` only need to be put at the bottom and the top of the code then I assume?

Comment: @Ohms No, generally speaking you don't. `On Error Resume Next` surpresses error handling entirely, causing you to overlook potentially meaningful and useful errors that would go otherwise unnoticed. Only time you should be really explciitly using it, is when you are intentionally error handling/accounting for an error (eg. trying to open file with specific name, which may potentially not exist, etc...)

Comment: @Ohms *to be put at the bottom and the top* Yes, as I stated.